# Building AOSP with AFWall

Tags: android, build, android-source, selinux

I want to build a (non rooted) AOSP 9 on my Pixel 2 with AFWall+ as system app, so I am able to lock my bootloader again and don't have to root my phone with other tools. Unfortunately, I don't have that much experience with Android rooting, yet. So my question is, which way is probably the easiest to give AFWall+ su-access.

So far my plan is to create a SEPolicy for AFWall by adding an entry in mac_permissions.xml and a afwall.te file in the ./sepolicy/vendor/ directory. But I've read enough about SELinux to understand, that I will not grasp all the complexity of it. So before I start to read into all those SE attributes and types, I would like to know, whether SE policies will be enough to give AFWall+ su access.

In case someone tells me that creating custom SEpolicies is in general a really bad idea as a beginner. Plan B is to activate root in the user build (by adjusting ./sepolicy/public/su.te) and add SuperSU and AFWall as system apps.

In short, those are my questions:

- Is a SEPolicy enough to give AFWall access to the su command?
- Is it an alternative to build AOSP with SuperSU and AFWall+?
- Should I maybe stop wasting my time and go the usual way (rooting, non locking bootloader)?
- In case my understanding of su access on Android is too naive: I would really appreciate, if someone could point me into the right direction.